# Loading UI Toolkit assetbundle from Mod

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written a mod for a video game that has a basic level of mod support, and provides a loader and access to game data etc. Currently the UI for the mod is using the IMGUI and I want to get rid of it.

I've been trying to write a proper UI in Unity, building an assetbundle but am struggling on getting my mod to actually load it.

As a POC I created the exact UI from the manual below, and the C# Script to build the bundle. This works, the manifest file lists my asset inside of the bundle.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-HowTo-CreateRuntimeUI.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/BuildingAssetBundles.html

Inside of the game when I try and load this asset from my mod at the most basic level I'm getting an error

> Unable to read header from archive file: C:/Test/CustomAsset/customui.assets
> Failed to read data for the AssetBundle

Script used to load test:

```
var bundleLoadRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(
            Path.Combine("C:\\Test\\CustomAsset", "customui.assets")); 
        Log(bundleLoadRequest.GetAllAssetNames().ToString());
```

I know this path is valid because if I type an invalid path I get a different error "unable to locate asset" or something to that effect. If someone could please assist in pointing me in the right direction

Comment: The link leads to the Unity 5.40 documentation? Are you using that old of a Unity version? Asset Bundles generally only work for the Unity version they are built with. Is it possible there is a mismatch between your editor and the version the game you are modding as created with?

Comment: @ephb No I was using the latest version from Unity's website. From AssetRipper it does the game was written with an older one 2020.3.34, so I will reattempt to build my assetbundle in that version. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if that is the only issue but that would absolutely not work.
Please report back if you have better luck with the matching Unity version.

Comment: That was the issue - when I created it in the matching version I didn't even need to load it as the game did automatically - thanks again

Comment: Great. I will post it as the answer then for others to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asset Bundles generally only work for the Unity version they are built with. Is it possible there is a mismatch between your editor version and the version the game you are modding was created with?

Sadly there is no Version check at the beginning that will let you know and they just won’t work.

Comment: Also to add, the other piece that tripped me up was the Unity version 2020.3 does not include the UI Toolkit by default, the game also is not using it, so systems like UIDocument were not natively available when executing the mod. I had to bring those DLLs with me.

Comment: UI Toolkit was not a default package for 2020.3 you could have added it trough the package manager instead. But good the including the DLLs manually worked too.

Comment: But how would I add it through package manager since I'm not actually using Unity's editor for my mod? I'm not loading any of the actual game through Unity itself - only using it to make my prefab assets

Comment: Ah I did not understand you  correctly. I am not into modding so you are probably right about bringing the dlls